# Using markdown in flextable caption

Tags: r, caption, flextable

I want to use bold and italics in a flextable caption. I know that it is possible to apply font syles to text within the header or body of a flextable using the `ftExtra` package and one can choose different output styles for a caption in word output by `officeR`. But either these do not work with the caption (ftExtra) or do not provide a style that allows selective application of bold and italics.

Here is some code with the intended markdown in the caption:

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)

iris[1:10,] %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  set_caption(caption = "**Tab. 1:** First ten (*n* = 10) samples of the Iris species dataset")
```

The caption should read as "**Tab. 1:** First ten (*n* = 10) samples of the Iris species dataset"

**UPDATE**

based on the comment by dario a possible solution would be:

```
  library(flextable)
  library(dplyr)

  iris[1:10,] %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  
  add_header_lines("") %>% 
  
  compose(
    i = 1, part = "header",
    value = as_paragraph(
      as_chunk("Table 1: ", props = fp_text(bold = TRUE)),
      as_chunk("First ten ("),
      as_chunk("n", props = fp_text(italic = TRUE)),
      as_chunk(" = 10) samples of the Iris species dataset")
    )
  )
```

Thank you very much. In the end I need to produce about 20 tables in different chapters and so I will try the suggestion by David to build the captions during knitting a markdown. But it is good to know that there is way, although clunky and not flexible using `compose`.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530204/is-there-a-way-to-bold-part-of-a-character-string-being-passed-to-add-header-lin) can help.  Not sure though if it applies to your usecase...

Comment: There is no support for markdown in `set_caption`. Why not using simple markdown before or after your table (if I remember correctly, you need to prefix it with `Table: `

Comment: @Jens, look at my solution, it is simpler ;)

Comment: @jens I don't think caption should be in the table because it must be usable in a list of tables, and this solution doesn't make it possible. manro'solution lets the caption be in a  list of tables, which is good

Comment: @DavidGohel yes, I agree. In the end I need multiple tables. However, it could be a quick solution for a single table.

Comment: @DavidGohel I have some wishes to improve your library, will i tell to you in the future about them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prepared a markdown template for you:

````
---
title: "Hello World"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{caption}

output:
  pdf_document: 
       latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)    
table2 <- flextable(mtcars[1:5, 1:6])        
```     
   
This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

\begin{table}[hbtp]
\captionof{table}{Text of the caption.}
`r table2`
\end{table}

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:
````

**An output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you - I guess the caption can be handled easily now.

Comment: @Jens gute Arbeit ;)